# Creating multiple dynamic objects NodeJs queries for Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, underscore.js

I have an array of objects

```
[ 
  {
    userId: '541c83d89ff44f767a23c546',
    emailArray: [ 
         'abc@amazon.com',
         'zxc@amazon.com',
         'pqr@amazon.com',
         'lol@amazon.com'
    ]
  },
  { 
    userId: '56bd6bf220591a124001d178',
    emailArray:[
         'mno@gmail.com',
         'uvw@gmail.com'
         'second@gmail.com'
    ]
  } 
]
```

and for each userId I want to create MongoDb query objects like below

```
var q1 = { $and: [ {userId:userId1}, {"interactions.emailId": {$in:emailArray1}
var q2 = { $and: [ {userId:userId2}, {"interactions.emailId": {$in:emailArray2}
var q3 = { $and: [ {userId:userId3}, {"interactions.emailId": {$in:emailArray3}
.....
var qn = { $and: [ {userId:userId(n)}, {"interactions.emailId": {$in:emailArray(n)}
```

where

> userId1 = 541c83d89ff44f767a23c546 and userId2 = 56bd6bf220591a124001d178

```
emailArray1 = [
    'abc@amazon.com',
    'zxc@amazon.com',
    'pqr@amazon.com',
    'lol@amazon.com'
]

emailaray2 = [
    'mno@gmail.com',
    'uvw@gmail.com'
    'second@gmail.com'
]
```

and so on.

then at the end a finally query object

```
var queryFinal = { $or: [ q1, q2,q3......qn] }
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: One more thing, in each query, you don't need a `$and`. Apart from that, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. Can you please explain on that?

Comment: I will be feeding this queryFinal to get some values from a collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use regular JavaScript:

```
var data = [ 
   { userId: '541c83d89ff44f767a23c546',
     emailArray: 
         [ 'abc@amazon.com',
           'zxc@amazon.com',
           'pqr@amazon.com',
          'lol@amazon.com' ]
   },
   { userId: '56bd6bf220591a124001d178',
     emailArray: 
         [ 'mno@gmail.com',
           'uvw@gmail.com',
           'second@gmail.com' ]
   }
];

var queryFinal = { "$or": data.map(function(el) {
    el["interactions.emailId"] = { "$in": el.emailArray };
    delete el.emailArray;
    return el;
}) };
```

**All** MongoDB query arguments are already an "AND" condition, therefore you don't need `$and` to be explicitly stated in most purposes.

Produces:

```
{
        "$or" : [
                {
                        "userId" : "541c83d89ff44f767a23c546",
                        "interactions.emailId" : {
                                "$in" : [
                                        "abc@amazon.com",
                                        "zxc@amazon.com",
                                        "pqr@amazon.com",
                                        "lol@amazon.com"
                                ]
                        }
                },
                {
                        "userId" : "56bd6bf220591a124001d178",
                        "interactions.emailId" : {
                                "$in" : [
                                        "mno@gmail.com",
                                        "uvw@gmail.com",
                                        "second@gmail.com"
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```